# Windows Service writing to windows TEMP folder

Tags: c++, windows, service

I am writing a simple windows service in C++. I can see the service in the list( when I run services.msc) but when I click "Start" after some time it comes back with a **Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"**.

I checked the windows event log and I see this:

**Would be blocked by access protection rule  (rule is in warn-only mode) (Common Standard Protection:Prevent common programs from running files from the Temp folder).** This is from McAfee

The exe that my service runs is in C:\Temp folder (and the file it creates is also in the C:\Temp folder), and NOT the windows temp folder. Is there a way that I can find what is trying to write to the temp folder.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://community.mcafee.com/thread/38446), it appears that it's a known issue with McAfee.

> *Any time you open an application by clicking on Start/Programs/ or by double-clicking on it, explorer.exe is what opens it.  In Windows, explorer.exe is your shell and it's what launches apps when you click on them.  McAfee is making a regular expression match on the path, which contains the string 'TEMP' (part of 'TEMPro6').  Yeah, it's kinda crappy coding on McAfee's part, but that's what you have to work with.*

Comment: Thank you, I changed my dir from C:\Temp to something like C:\ABC and dont get that error anymore in the event log, the service still doesnt start (still getting the 1503 error) but thats a diff problem. :)